# Метод или свойство Protect недоступны, потому что эту команду нельзя использовать в режиме чтения .Net

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

Использую библиотеку: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.
Сам Word 2016 года.
Программа копирует файл в папку С:\temp, сам документ редактируется, после чего перемещается в другую папку.
Программа отваливается в этом куске кода:

```
var newPath = @"C:\temp";
if (CopyTemplateFile(report.Template, newPath)) {
    _app.Visible = false;
    _doc = _app.Documents.Open(tempTemplateFile);
    //_doc.ReadOnlyRecommended = false;
}
else return;

_doc.Protect(WdProtectionType.wdNoProtection);

if (_doc.ProtectionType != WdProtectionType.wdNoProtection) {
    _doc.Unprotect();
}

deleteTempFiles = report.is_deletetempfile;
FillDocument(report.main);
SaveDocument(report.ReportFileName, newPath);
```

На методе _doc.Protect() вылезает следующая ошибка:

```
    WordWrapper: Метод или свойство Protect недоступны, потому что эту команду нельзя использовать в режиме чтения. 
  в Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass.Protect(WdProtectionType Type, Object& NoReset, Object& Password, Object& UseIRM, Object& EnforceStyleLock)
       в wrd.routings.lib.WordWrapper..ctor(Report report)  
Void Protect(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdProtectionType, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)  Microsoft Word
```

С чем это может быть связано? Метод Protect убрать не могу, т.к иначе программа просто перетащит пустой файл

Comment: Предварительно надо выйти из режима защищенного чтения.